# Creating a multi boot usb drive containing windows to go, Ubuntu and falcon fours

Tags: ubuntu, usb, multi-boot, bootable-media, windows-to-go

hi I am new to the world of multi booting,
i am trying to create a multi boot usb with, windows to go, Ubuntu and falcon fours.
i tried using yumi but there is no option of installing a win to go,
i would appreciative any help or what to look into

Answer (score -1):

Easy2Boot will boot directly from linux ISOs and other ISOs, VHDs and WIM files. It also supports linux+persistence, UEFI-booting and even Secure UEFI-booting.
WindowsToGo is a full installation of Windows on a USB drive.
You can create a WindowsToGo USB Flash drive using WinToUSB which uses a VHD file. Then simply copy the VHD file to the multiboot Easy2Boot drive.