# Multiboot USB with OTG Windows

Tags: windows, usb, multi-boot, liveusb

How can I create a multiboot USB with Windows On The Go as 1 of the boot options? Ideally with [MultiBootUSB](http://multibootusb.org/).

Maybe I can create Windows OTG ISO from original one?

Tried to find answer from [Creating a multi boot usb drive containing windows to go, Ubuntu and falcon fours](https://superuser.com/a/1350190/1135082), but failed, because answer was not detailed enough (for me).

Comment: Use https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/ ; Use it to edit windows bootloader or install grub > Add new entries for iso you want to boot (refer: https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/portable-entries/iso-images/)

Comment: Maybe I can create Windows OTG ISO from original one? - Explain a little more what you mean

Comment: @Madhubala, I absolutely have no clue, how do images and live images work. That was an assumption.

Comment: @Madhubala your method allows me to multiboot to installed OSes. I'm talking about multiboot USB with live images.

Comment: The ISO images are live images of any Linux distribution and not installed OS es. Grub2 directly supports booting from live ISO (refer - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot ). I will suggest you to use grub2 directly instead of using EascyBCD (i think it's a little buggy) if you are fine with grub instead of Windows bootloader.

Comment: @Madhubala so I need to install grub2 directly on USB and then move images on the USB? Why I am asking this question is that because (AFAIK) Windows images don't have out of the box on the go solution. The only way to install OTG Windows on USB is through Rufus or something because there is an option "Install OTG Windows", so I guess it manipulates somehow with the image while installing it on USB.

Comment: Create Windows OTG > Boot and set-up your Windows completely > (assuming you have a another live USB of linux use it to ) Install grub on USB and generate grub.cfg , taking care that your windows is detected while generating configuration file. > Place the ISO  > Edit the configuration file and add new entries

Comment: `Create Windows OTG` you mean flash USB with Windows OTG image? And on this USB I have to change bootloader to grub2? So after I'll have USB with extracted Windows OTG and some .img files for linux live distros?

Comment: Yes to every question except why .IMG files ? You can use normal ISO images downloaded from the respective sites of Linux distributions but if you are interested in booting IMG files refer https://superuser.com/questions/412028/booting-an-ext4-image-file-from-grub2

Comment: @Madhubala my bad, meant ISO files. But maybe there is a way to store Windows To Go on USB in ISO too?

Comment: Windows ISO aren't live images.

Comment: @Madhubala that's the problem I'm trying to find a solution to :(